# Fetch first row only with IN operation in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, greatest-n-per-group

how do i use "fetch first row only" in combination with "in" operator? something like

```
select user_id, item_name as last_item_name 
from sale 
where user_id in (1,2) 
order by date desc 
fetch first row only
```

which i want it to returns the last item each person buy?
eg: running the query on

```
--------------------------------
id | user_id | item_name| date |
1  | 1       | pen      | 01/01|
2  | 1       | book     | 02/01|
3  | 2       | book     | 01/01|
4  | 2       | computer | 02/01|
--------------------------------
```

should return

```
user_id | last_item_name|
1       | book          |
2       | computer      |
-------------------------
```

Thanks!

Comment: classic [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem (where the group is by person, and "greatest" is the latest date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want latest per user? Use `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.user_id ORDER BY t.date DESC) as rnk
    FROM sale t
    WHERE t.user_id IN(1,2)) s
WHERE s.rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

```
with uniquserid as (
select distinct user_id from sale 
)
select f1.user_id , f3.item_name 
from uniquserid f1
inner join lateral 
(
select * from sale f2
where f1.user_id =f2.user_id 
ORDER BY f2.date DESC
fetch first rows only 
) f3 on 1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2

```
select f1.user_id , f3.item_name 
from 
(select distinct user_id from sale) f1
inner join lateral 
(
select * from sale f2
where f1.user_id =f2.user_id
ORDER BY f2.date DESC
fetch first rows only 
) f3 on 1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 3

```
 with uniquserid as (
 select distinct user_id from sale 
 )
 select f1.user_id , (select f2.item_name from sale f2 where f1.user_id =f2.user_id ORDER BY f2.date DESC
 fetch first rows only) as item_name 
 from uniquserid f1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 4

```
select f1.user_id , (select f2.item_name from sale f2 where f1.user_id =f2.user_id ORDER BY f2.date DESC
fetch first rows only) as item_name 
from (select distinct user_id from sale) f1
```